# How to emit router event

Tags: javascript, angular, router, eventemitter, router-outlet

I have 2 modules, one is sidenav, where I can select the menu and want to show component in `content module` where have `router-outlet`. I want to know what is the best way to do that? Have some `router event` where I can just `subscribe` in content module? Because I will use `service` to `emit` component and `subscribe event in router-outlet` component, but I guess that is not best practice. Something like that:

```
Service:
private emit = EventEmitter<string>
emit(component: string): void {
 this.emit.emit(component)
}
```

and in component I just subscribe in `service emit` and use `router.navigate` to show component in `router-outlet`. Hope someone can help me =). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly :

**Sidenav**

```
@Output() navigate: EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter();

emit (route: string[]) {
  this.navigate.emit(route);
}
```

**Parent of sidenav**

```
<app-sidenav (navigate)="router.navigate($event)"></app-sidenav>
```

Remember to make the router public in the parent component :

```
constructor(public router: Router) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

child-component
HTML

```
<app-child
[formGroup]="formChild"
(navigate)="onNavigate($event)"
></app-child>
```

TS

```
@Output() navigate: EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter();
  route = ['yourUrl'];


  onNavigate(route: string[]) {
    this.route = route;
    this.navigate.emit(route);
    //console.log(route);
  }
```

Parent component

```
goBack(){
    this.router.navigate(['yourRoute']);
  }
```

Hope to be helpful!